# Как подсчитать количество комбинаций точек. С#

Tags: c#, массивы, математика

Есть массив координат точек класcа Point

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }
}

static void Main(string[] args)
{
  Point[] arrayPoint = new Point[10];
}
```

Как подсчитать количество комбинаций точек из четырех и все возможные комбинации добавить в массив?

пример `arrayPoint[3], arrayPoint [2], arrayPoint [1], arrayPoint [7]` - первая комбинация. `arrayPoint[2], arrayPoint [5], arrayPoint [6], arrayPoint [4]` - вторая комбинация. Их я так понимаю может быть много

Comment: https://www.matburo.ru/tvart_sub.php?p=calc_C

Comment: Что значит из четырёх? Вам надо 4 точки раскидать в 10?

Comment: ну на пример `arrayPoint[3], arrayPoint [2],  arrayPoint [1],  arrayPoint [7]` первая комбинация.  `arrayPoint[2], arrayPoint [5],  arrayPoint [6],  arrayPoint [4]`  - вторая комбинация

Comment: Порядок точек важен? Т. Е. (3,2,1,7) и (2,3,1,7) это одинаковые или разные?

Comment: Чтобы посчитать количество комбинаций, воспользуйтесь формулами из комбинаторики.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот решение.

```
public class Point
{
    public int X { get; set; }

    public int Y { get; set; }
}

Point[] arrayPoint = new Point[]
        {new Point{ X = 60, Y = 40},
            new Point{ X = 10, Y = 30},
            new Point{ X = 40, Y = 30},
            new Point{ X = 50, Y = 5},
            new Point{ X = 50, Y = 60},
            new Point{ X = 40, Y = 60},
            new Point{ X = 20, Y = 50},
            new Point{ X = 50, Y = 45},
            new Point{ X = 40, Y = 45},
            new Point{ X = 10, Y = 40},
            new Point{ X = 55, Y = 35},
            new Point{ X = 35, Y = 35},
            new Point{ X = 65, Y = 25},
            new Point{ X = 25, Y = 25},
            new Point{ X = 40, Y = 20},
            new Point{ X = 30, Y = 20},
            new Point{ X = 10, Y = 20},
            new Point{ X = 50, Y = 10},
            new Point{ X = 30, Y = 10},
            new Point{ X = 10, Y = 10}
        };

var arraySort = await Task.Run(() => sort.SortArray(arrayPoint));
```

```html
public class SortClass
    {
        public List<Rectangle> SortArray(Point[] array)
        {
            Rectangle rectangle;

            List<Rectangle> result = new List<Rectangle>();

            for (int a = 0; a < array.Length - 3; a++)
            {
                for (int b = a + 1; b < array.Length - 2; b++)
                {
                    for (int c = b + 1; c < array.Length - 1; c++)
                    {
                        for (int d = c + 1; d < array.Length; d++)
                        {
                            rectangle = new Rectangle()
                            {
                                One = array[a],
                                Two = array[b],
                                Three = array[c],
                                Four = array[d]
                            };
                            result.Add(rectangle);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
    }
```